# Universal App using Health Kit

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios-universal-app, healthkit

I'm working on an App which uses some new iOS 8 Health Kit (HK) features.

At present the iPad doesn't get the Health app, so can't use HK. Since the HK features are not a major part of my app functionality, I could happily leave them out of the iPad version.

My problem is that there seems no way to get a universal app running on iPad once the HK entitlements have been added, even if no use is made of HK functionality.

Does anyone know any different? Is there a way (for example) to have separate 'per device' entitlements?

Thanks!

Comment: How about two applications with the same code base: one, for iPhone-only has the HK entitlements and functionality, the other, for iPad-only lacks the HK entitlements and functionality.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking that would have to be my fall back option, but I wanted to keep it seperate for ease. I've just found this thread though which answers my Q:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647938/ios-universal-app-with-healthkit-wont-run-on-ipad/25658268#25658268 - hope this helps anyone else looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `healthkit` from `Required device capabilities` in my Info.plist solve this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use HealthKit, Framework Reference clearly states that your app should be primarily designed to provide health or fitness service. If your app is not a health or fitness focused app, you might not able to submit your universal app .

> In addition, your app must not access the HealthKit APIs unless the
>   app is primarily designed to provide health or fitness services. Your
>   app's role as a health and fitness service must be clear in both your
>   marketing text and your user interface. Specifically, the following
>   guidelines apply to all HealthKit apps.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Framework/index.html

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the guidelines in the above statement. Based on the quoted information the guidelines clearly state the app must be "primarily designed to provide health or fitness services".  This is very different to being "primarily developed for HealthKit".

Comment: I couldn't see the part that I say "primarily developed for HealthKit" ?

Comment: That’s because you edited your answer after I posted! It’s still visible in the original edit my friend.

Comment: Sorry my friend :) It's been a while, thought the comment is new and was trying to understand and fix the issue. Thanks for your correction.