# Apple Healthkit and iOS 7 deployment target

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, healthkit

When trying to submit an app through Xcode or Application loader, with the "healthkit" entitlement enabled and a deployment target of 7.0, the app store gives the following error:

> ERROR ITMS-9000: This bundle is invalid. The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities contains value 'healthkit' which is incompatible with the MinimumOSVersion value of '7.0'.

The confusing thing is, both [Strava](https://itunes.apple.com/no/app/strava-running-cycling-gps/id426826309?mt=8) and [UP](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/up-band-required-up-up24/id461125277?mt=8) have HealthKit enabled and iOS7 deployment targets. So it is technically possible to submit an app with these requirements.

Can someone please let me know how this is possible, so I can have HealthKit and not lose out on half of the current iOS marketshare?

Comment: The HealthKit feature requires iOS 8.

Comment: Indeed. So how have Strava and UP gotten around that requirement?

Comment: A related issue is discussed on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647938/ios-universal-app-with-healthkit-wont-run-on-ipad. It could help you possibly

Comment: Thanks @spassas, deleting the healthkit key from the info plist seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key is used to say that your app will only work with a certain feature (or inversely without it). You should only set this if your app requires HealthKit as opposed to supporting it.

Comment: This is correct. It's regrettable that Xcode automatically includes that value for healthkit and provides no indication that it is optional.

Comment: Does it do this also when the deployment is iOS 7 when HealthKit is added? If so this seems like a bug.

Comment: This also addresses a similar issue I got when submitting to iTunes connect: `The app's Info.plist can't contain values for the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key that would prevent this app from opening on any iOS device`.